# out of memory in react native android

Tags: react-native

[MEMORY ISSUE ON ANDROID]
hi all,
We're developing the application called Pippip at pippip.vn . It works very well on iOS but it has the problem on Android, it's out of memory when we load more large images, does anyone know how to fix it? Thanks all

Comment: How are you loading the images? Are you using a list view? How many are there? whats the size of the image? Also are you testing on a real phone?

Comment: Yes, we;re using the list view. We load 50 images each time and the size of image is 2048 * 2048. We tested on the real phone

Comment: i'm having the same issue as I'm loading the images in the viewPager.. either the app crashes for out of memory else the images doesn't render

Comment: I'm using React Native version 0.29.0 and also seeing this issue on android. Throwing OutOfMemoryError "Failed to allocate a 20 byte allocation with 0 free bytes and 3GB until OOM"

Comment: Did anyone fixed this problem ??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had similar issues, fix [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44429798/compressing-base64-encoded-images-in-react-native-on-android-does-not-recognise/44646080#44646080). Before rendering the full image, we compressed the photo based on the screen size to discard information that is not visible on the screen (resolution wise).